# Resizing 3 images with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to resize 3 images with javascript. How can i do that without having an ID and without having possibility to add one?
I have tried this but i don t know how to select all images(i need to set the width to 50px).

```
let images=document.querySelector('img');
images.setAttribute("width",50);
```

Comment: With CSS? `img { width:50px; }` ?

Comment: i can-t use css. only js

Comment: "I'm a mechanic but I'm not allowed to use a wrench" urghhhhh

Answer (score 2):

Is [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) what you're looking for? `document.querySelectorAll()` will select **all** elements matching a certain selector, not just the first.
In your case, it might be

```js
let images=document.querySelectorAll('img');
images.forEach(img => img.setAttribute("width",50));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use CSS to change the image width pick up the images with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then iterate over the node list of images and change the width of each one.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
images.forEach(image => image.setAttribute('width', '50px'));
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `querySelectorAll`

```js
changeSize = () => {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].style.width = "100px";
  }
}
originSize = () => {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].removeAttribute("style");
  }
}
```

```css
.images {
  display: flex;
}

.images img {
  margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeSize()">Change Size</button>
<button onclick="originSize()">Origin Size</button>
<div class='images'>
  <img src="https://cdnp2.stackassets.com/b1284961a6fbcbcfabe6f69c2ae4219ff6daa5e0/store/opt/596/298/1ca89e578fc4e326fe08196758c1688929acc8c5eeb8572e2282628cad78/product_30565_product_shot_wide.jpg" />

  <img src="https://cdnp2.stackassets.com/b1284961a6fbcbcfabe6f69c2ae4219ff6daa5e0/store/opt/596/298/1ca89e578fc4e326fe08196758c1688929acc8c5eeb8572e2282628cad78/product_30565_product_shot_wide.jpg" />

  <img src="https://cdnp2.stackassets.com/b1284961a6fbcbcfabe6f69c2ae4219ff6daa5e0/store/opt/596/298/1ca89e578fc4e326fe08196758c1688929acc8c5eeb8572e2282628cad78/product_30565_product_shot_wide.jpg" />
</div>
```